# trouble with jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Trying to implement an autocomplete based on [this](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#intro)

It looks like it's very straight forward but I cannot get this one to work with an ajax call. By not working, I mean I don't see the drop down. Firebug shows no errors.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var options, a;

  jQuery(function(){
  options = { serviceUrl:'vendors1.cfm', 
              delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/,
              deferRequestBy: 0,
              minChars:2};
 a = $('#query').autocomplete(options); 
  });
 </script>
```

now the vendors1.cfm, returns a ';' seperated list: ABC CONSTRUCTION;ABC CONSTRUCTION;ABC CONSTRUCTION;ABC PLUMBING & ELECTRICAL SUPPLY INC  etc.

how do i properly use the `serviceURL`. what format do I have to output the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the dev web page:

Web page that provides data for Ajax Autocomplete, `vendors1.cfm`  will receive GET request with query string as `?query="query string"`, and it must return JSON data in the following format:

```
{
 query:'Li',
 suggestions:['Liberia','Libyan Arab Jamahiriya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania'],
 data:['LR','LY','LI','LT']
}
```

- `query` - original query value
- `suggestions` - comma separated array of suggested values
- `data (optional)` - data array, that contains values for callback function when data is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You should return valid JSON.
e.g. If you typed "Li" in the textfield you could return:

```
{
 query:'Li',
 suggestions:['Liberia','Libyan Arab Jamahiriya','Liechtenstein','Lithuania'] 
}
```

The delimiter is not used for the returned values but it will allow you to enter multiple values with autocomplete.

If you accept "," as a delimiter it will allow you to type: "Netherlands,Li" and the autocomplete will work as if you typed "Li"

Comment: I am returning JSON now but then i get "response.suggestions is undefined" in firebug. it points to jquery.autocomplete.js line 293.